# Разница между return (val) и return val

Tags: java

Есть ли разница между `return (val)` и `return val`?

Answer (score 6):

Нет никакой разницы. Что-то указывается в скобках обычно для улучшения читаемости (в выражениях так может расставляться приоритет операций).

---

Аналогично работают скобки: например, такие выражения будут полностью аналогичны в плане работы, но первое лучше читается:

```
(variable == null) ? this.pullVariable(variable) : this.pushVariable(variable);
variable == null ? this.pullVariable(variable) : this.pushVariable(variable);
```

---

Также в Java скобки с типом используются для преобразования. Например:

```
Object object = (Object) variable;
```

Так же преобразование может использоваться с оператором `return`:

```
return (Object) variable;
```

Comment: или что бы повысить приоритет)

Comment: @crowlie, я дополнил.

Comment: Читается может оно и лучше в первом случае, везде свои правила. Но первый случай как бы намекает, на незнание приоритетов операции как следствие излишние скобки. Извиняюсь за такой коментарий, но не мог не написать. Ответ полезен вне сомнений)